# What does the OFFSET do in repaint()-method with varargs?

Tags: java, swing, paint, offset, repaint

```
 private void moveSquare(int x, int y) {
    int OFFSET = 1;
    if ((squareX!=x) || (squareY!=y)) {
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
    } 
}
```

This is a snippet from the Java-Tutorials. It's a tutorial about painting in Java. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html

I don't understand what the OFFSET is **exactly** doing.
Or what happens **inside** the repaint()-method.

I know, that it is necessary to paint the square correctly, because I noticed, that without the OFFSET, the Square is sometimes missing a side, which is not painted, or not deleted by the first repaint()-method.

I let the program write the variables (used for painting the rectangle (squareX...and so on)) in the console. But the width and heigth were always 20 and not 21 (width + OFFSET). Even when I read the variables inside the paintComponent()-method.
That is why I don't understand, why the **square is drawn correctly the very first** time, but every other time it gets repainted without the OFFSET, then it is drawn incorrectly.

And I can't look inside the repaint()-method (at least I don't know how to do it)

Another little question: Does the repaint method always "delete / overwrite" the object (in this case the square) it wants to draw, if the variables like color, position haven't changed?

This is what the paintComponent()-method is doint.

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
```

What I don't understand is, why the first repaint()-method deletes the old square. squareX/Y/W/H are the same as before. Afterwards they get the new coordinates from the mouse click, and then the square gets painted at the new location.
Why does the same code delete in the first repaint() and in the second one it creates a new square?

Sorry, if my english is bad. I'm from Germany.

Thanks in advance for all your answers!!!

Comment: Typically, coordinates are zero based, so a square that is 20 pixels wide is going to be something like 0-19.  Adding the additional pixel overcomes this slight inconstancy.  The `repaint` method you are calling sets up a clipping rectangle which updates only that portion of the component, it won't change the size of the `squareW/H` vaues

Comment: *"Another little question: Does the repaint method always "delete / overwrite" the object (in this case the square) it wants to draw, if the variables like color, position haven't changed?"* - No or more to the point, that depends on what the `paintComponent` method is actually doing.  If the area which is to updated hasn't changed, then from your perspective, it won't change, but it will have been repainted or updated.  This is why you need to repaint the old position before you repaint the new, otherwise you what ever existed at the old position will remain

Comment: thanks for your super quick answers! I will have a quick update because theres a small thing I still don't understand about the second question.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand what the OFFSET is exactly doing.

I think this comes down to how what a `width` and `height` value actually is.

Generally speaking, most people see a `width` and `height` as been `1` indexed (`1 to width/height`), where as the computer sees it as `0` indexed (`0 to width/height`).

So, when you define a area as been 20 pixels wide/high, is it 0-20, 0-19 or 1-20?

You can see this if you try and draw a rectangle surrounding the entire component.  If you were to do something like....

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

the right/bottom edges would appear of the screen, instead, you need to use something more like

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
```

What is happening here is, the API is allowing for both circumstances.  The size of the component (defined by the `width` and `height` properties) is represented as `1` indexed, but we need to adjust for this to make it `0` indexed.

Why EXACTLY this is happening is beyond my knowledge (and generally my caring), all I care about is knowing that it happens ;)

> Or what happens inside the repaint()-method.

Generally, you shouldn't.  What you should care about is the fact that the API provides a consistent result, as the underlying workings of the API are delegating to native functionality (DirectX or OpenGL in most cases)

> I let the program write the variables (used for painting the rectangle (squareX...and so on)) in the console. But the width and heigth were always 20 and not 21 (width + OFFSET). Even when I read the variables inside the paintComponent()-method.
>   That is why I don't understand, why the square is drawn correctly the very first time, but every other time it gets repainted without the OFFSET, then it is drawn incorrectly.

You wouldn't.  The `repaint` isn't changing the physical state of the variables, but instead is asking that a small area of the component be updated, without effecting the rest of the component.  What the API does is generate a clipping rectangle (see, it's another rectangle), which only allows updates to appear within that area (painting beyond it has no effect).

This is why it's called twice, once for the old position and once for the new

> Another little question: Does the repaint method always "delete / overwrite" the object (in this case the square) it wants to draw, if the variables like color, position haven't changed?

It depends.  Painting is considered destructive, that is, each time `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to repaint the entire state of the component from scratch.  So, even if the state hasn't changed, the entire area must be repainted, because the `paintComponent` has no idea what the previous state was.

In Swing, the `Graphics` context is a shared resource, it is used to paint all the components for a common native peer.

You could have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) which might provide you with some more information about the painting process

Comment: Wow, thank you for your detailed answer. Yeah, you're right, it's enough to know how to fight this problem! ;) But your answer made me understand what is happening! Thanks a lot. I will also have a look at the sites you recommended! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand, why the square is drawn correctly the very first time,

The `paintComponent(...)` method is invoked WITHOUT clipping, so the entire (250 x 200) area of the panel is repainted.

> but every other time it gets repainted without the OFFSET, then it is drawn incorrectly.

When you click on the panel the `paintComponent(...)` method is invoked WITH clipping as the two `repaint(...)` requests are consolidated into a single clipped painting request to make the painting more efficient.

For example, initially the square is painted at (50, 50). If you now click at (80, 80) the area repainted will be: (50, 50, 101, 101), which is the minimum area needed to clear the old square and paint the new square.

You can see the size of the clipped area change by adding the following to the paintComponent() method:

```
System.out.println(g.getClipBounds());
```

Note: for a simple painting like this you don't really need to be fancy. You could just invoke a single `repaint()` statement after resetting the x/y values and the entire panel will be repainted.